# c++ How to read from a file into array one word at a time

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I *know* this is a dumb question!

But I just CAN NOT get my head around how to read my file into an array one word at a time using c++

Here is the code for what I was trying to do - with some attempted output.

```
void readFile()
{
   int const maxNumWords = 256;
   int const maxNumLetters = 32 + 1;
   int countWords = 0;
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open ("madLib.txt");
   if (!fin.is_open()) return;

   string word;
   while (fin >> word)
   {
      countWords++;
      assert (countWords <= maxNumWords);
   }

   char listOfWords[countWords][maxNumLetters];
   for (int i = 0; i <= countWords; i++)
   {
      while (fin >> listOfWords[i]) //<<< THIS is what I think I need to change 
                                    //buggered If I can figure out from the book what to
      {
         // THIS is where I want to perform some manipulations - 
         // BUT running the code never enters here (and I thought it would)
         cout <<  listOfWords[i];
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to get each word (defined by a space between words) from the madLib.txt file into the listOfWords array so that I can then perform some character by character string manipulation.

Clearly I can read from a file and get that into a string variable - BUT that's not the assignment (Yes this is for a coding class at college)

I have read from a file to get integers into an array - but I can't quite see how to apply that here...

Comment: The first loop reads until the end of the file, the second loop is trying to read more. That cannot succeed at the end of the file.

Comment: I've just tried the 2nd loop with this i <= countWords -1 ;  No difference...   The first loop is just telling me how many words in the file.
2nd loop is trying to read each word into the listOfWords[i] array 1 i position at a time - then cout the word so I can confirm it was read (Once I figure this out will then be manipulating it...

Comment: @kiltannen You also have to `clear()` the input stream. Forgot that sorry. But I'd recommend you use the method I've sketched out in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can imagine to do this is:

```
void readFile()
{
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open ("madLib.txt");
   if (!fin.is_open()) return;

   vector<string> listOfWords;
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<string>(fin), std::istream_iterator<string>()
            , std::back_inserter(listOfWords));
}
```

---

Anyways, you stated in your question you want to read one word at a time and apply manipulations. Thus you can do the following:

```
void readFile()
{
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open ("madLib.txt");
   if (!fin.is_open()) return;

   vector<string> listOfWords;
   string word;
   while(fin >> word) {
        // THIS is where I want to perform some manipulations
        // ...
        listOfWords.push_back(word);
   }
}
```

Comment: While I like the apparent elegance of this answer  we haven't yet covered vectors. I am confident this would be an issue, as the course is very clear I can NOT copy code.  I would love to understand what is happening with your other suggestion OF fin.seekg(0);  - and I think I can research that and be comfortable it will not breach course restrictions...

Comment: @kiltannen Well, that you're not allowed to use `std::vector` is a silly restriction, and only your very personal problem. In the spirit that Q&A at Stack Overflow should be helpful for _everyone_ I'll leave my answer here.

Comment: No problem at all with you leaving the elegant answer you have written. Just trying to figure out quite the syntax & position on the clear() for the input stream...

Comment: @kiltannen Just before you start reading from the stream again. After your 1st loop there's the eof flag still set, so you have to clear it.

Comment: So I imagine if I close the file and open it again that'll accomplish this.  I've just been reading a bit of the documentation for the .seekg(0)  and it sadly is not as simple for me as it is for you.  I figure I'll get there, eventually.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @kiltannen `fin.clear(); fin.seekg(0);` should be sufficient. No need to close and reopen the file.

Comment: And this has worked...!!!   YES a vector would be more elegant.  BUT this is also a successful approach - and more defensible on my course I suspect.  Thank You!

Comment: @kiltannen You shouldn't write the working solution into your question, this will confuse people. Rather put the working solution as a self answer (and may be mark it as _community wiki_).

Answer (score 0):

On the suggestion of πάντα ῥεῖ

I've tried this:

```
void readFile()
{
   int const maxNumWords = 256;
   int const maxNumLetters = 32 + 1;
   int countWords = 0;
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open ("madLib.txt");
   if (!fin.is_open()) return;

   string word;
   while (fin >> word)
   {
          countWords++;
          assert (countWords <= maxNumWords);
   }
```

> ```
>    fin.clear();
>    fin.seekg(0);
> ```

```
   char listOfWords[countWords][maxNumLetters];
   for (int i = 0; i <= countWords; i++)
   {
  while (fin >> listOfWords[i]) //<<< THIS did NOT need changing
  {
     // THIS is where I want to perform some manipulations - 
     cout <<  listOfWords[i];
   }
}
```

and it has worked for me.  I do think using vectors is more elegant, and so have accepted that answer.

The suggestion was also made to post this as a self answer rather than as an edit - which I kind of agree is sensible so I've gone ahead and done so.

Answer (score -1):

The most simple way to do that is using the STL algorithm... Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;

    auto beginStream = istream_iterator<string>{cin};
    auto eos = istream_iterator<string>{};
    copy(beginStream, eos, back_inserter(words));    

    // print the content of words to standard output
    copy(begin(words), end(words), ostream_iterator<string>{cout, "\n"});
}
```

Instead of `cin` of course, you can use any `istream` object (like `file`)